# Conjugation of element lying in product of 3 groups lies in product of two groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading an article about tree automorphisms and I've got a problem whith something. Here it is:

> if $w \in \langle \gamma ^{h_1} \rangle \langle \gamma ^{h_2} \rangle \langle \gamma ^{h_1} \rangle$ then conjugation of $w$ lies in $\langle \gamma ^{h_1'} \rangle \langle \gamma ^{h_2'} \rangle$

So we know that $w=h_1^{-1} \gamma^i h_1 h_2^{-1} \gamma ^j h_2h_1^{-1} \gamma ^k h_1$ and I'm stucked... I was trying to consider conjugations like $w^{h_1}, w^{h_2}$ etc. but I've got nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\gamma^{-i} h_1) \, w \, (\gamma^{-i} h_1)^{-1}$